# Connect Pi to computer and be recognized as a keyboard and mouse

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I would like to connect the Pi to my computer (through USB?) and have the computer think that it is a keyboard and mouse. This should be a completely external thing. The end project I am working on will have my laptop take mouse and keyboard commands from the Pi that I am remotely logged into.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on Raspberry Pi model you can or can't acomplish this task.

It depends on the USB hardware interface.

Model A, A+ and Zero has the hardware so it supports the USB OTG/Gadget.

Model 2 and 3 doesn't support USB OTG/Gadget.

Comment: Is there any realistic option available (even using another device) where I can hook up my multiple computers and interact with them all remotely as if I was there without installing software directly on them? I have 4 devices that are a pain to carry around, but I often have to travel. Some are basically locked down for various reasons.